# consume a webservice and store it in database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, rest

I'm new in `Webservices`, I have a `Webservice`(java - restful) created by a colleague which I need to consume from my project(`visual basic` - `asp.net`)and save it into my `SQL database`.
When i go to the link of the `webservice` using the browser, it shows the following:

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below:

```
<despacho>
<estadoParaMostrar>Cerrado</estadoParaMostrar>
<estado_despacho>CER</estado_despacho>
<fechacierre>2016-12-07T00:00:00-05:00</fechacierre>
<fechaingreso>2016-11-25T00:00:00-05:00</fechaingreso>
<id_empleado>1456</id_empleado>
<id_origen>3</id_origen>
</despacho>
```

From what i understood, This shows a record with the parameters (estadoParaMostrar, estado_despacho, fechacierre, fechaingreso, id_empleado, id_origen). This `webservices` contain more than 100 records.
What i need to do is to create an `interface` with a `button` that allows me to consume the `webservice` and these records would be immediately insert into a table in the `SQL database`.
I'm not quite sure if this is possible or How can i do it.

Comment: this is asp.net but give it a read: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/100803-1.aspx

Comment: @wazz, a link from 2003? And this service is clearly not SOAP.

Comment: hello guys, thanks for your help, i've been searchin for some information ang  got this

Comment: Dim proxy As New WebClient()
    Dim serviceurl As String = String.Format("http://10.228.100.255:8090/RestfulWeb/Displacement/despachos")
     Dim _data As Byte() = proxy.DownloadData(serviceurl)
     Dim _mem As Stream = New MemoryStream(_data)
     Dim reader = New StreamReader(_mem)
     Dim result = reader.ReadToEnd()

Comment: I place a breakpoint and seems to be that the content is in the result variable, now i would need to insert into table or at least shows into gridview

Comment: @Crowcoder not really sure why i did that...

Comment: You really have two questions here. Google how to deserialize an xml stream to an object and also how to use ADO.Net then ask new questions if you get stuck on some code.

Comment: Hello guys, thank you very much for your advice, i search for a code to deserialize the xml stream and i was able to save the webservice content in a tablle in my database.